# View Routes dynamic data array in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view, controller, routes

In laravel Document View Route is defined with array of data

Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome', ['name' => 'Taylor']);

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#view-routes

how can I pass value to it from a view

Comment: Passing value from what to where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass value from view to controller like this,

```
Route::get('routeUrl/{id}',[
    'as' => 'routeName',
    'uses' => 'YourControllerName@yourFunction'
]);
```

Your href be like

`<a href="{{ route('routeName',['id' => 10 }}">Link</a>`

Your url will be `abc/routeUrl/10`

in your controller you can receive the value

```
public function yourFunction($id)
{
    //
}
```